# How to get specific array of properties from DS.Promisearray

Tags: javascript, ember.js

is it possible get specific parameters from promise array?

I have model:

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  length: DS.attr('string'),
  time: DS.attr('string'),
  number: DS.attr('string')
})
```

after `this.store.find('item')` I get DS.PromiseArray. For graphs purposes I need something like
[[time1, number1],[time2, number2],[time3, number3] ....]

I have tried `.getEach('time')` and `.getEach('number')` for individual list of the property and How can I connect it together?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
this.store.find('item').then(function(items) {
  return items.map(function(item) {
    return [item.get('time'), item.get('number')];
  })
});
```

Comment: New problem: this code return: Object { _promiseCallbacks={...}, constructor=function(), isRejected=undefined, more...} and data are saved in fullfilmentValue. How can I set this values to simple array or object?

Comment: Strange, I think that you are receiving a PromiseArray instead of an array. But in that fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/DGT5L/. The returned array is correct

Comment: Yes, I'm receiving a PromiseArray:<DS.PromiseArray:ember500> { isRejected=false, isFulfilled=false, concatenatedProperties=[1], more...}, it is from this.store.findQuery()

Comment: I recommend you to create a new question, reporting this problem and with a fiddle simulating.